# Visa to Egypt and passport control

Tags: visas, air-travel, customs-and-immigration, lebanese-citizens

I will be visiting the USA this July for 3 weeks. I am a Lebanese woman (I have a Lebanese passport only) married to an Egyptian citizen and living in Egypt. I was granted a US visitor visa for 5 years.

Per Egyptian laws, I don't need an Egyptian visa. All I have to do when I return to Egypt is to show passport control my marriage certificate in order to enter. My concern is when I am departing the USA, will the US passport control allow my departure based on my marriage certificate too? What do you advise I should do if the marriage certificate was not enough as a document for departure?

Comment: The US does not have direct passport controls on exit.  The airline will pass information about your departure to the US.  The US also has no rules regarding the admissibility of those who leave the country at their place of arrival.  Only the airline will care about that.  So, the only question you need to answer is whether the *airline* will accept your documents.  Unfortunately, I do not know the answer to that.

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia [agrees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Egypt#Visa_exemption) that no visa is required for Lebanese wives of Egyptians with proof of marriage.

> Visa exemption also applies to
>   sons and daughters born to an Egyptian fathers (except nationals of Syria, Iraq, Yemen and Qatar) having an Egyptian mother and being born after 25 July 2004 (except nationals of Syria, Iraq, Qatar and Yemen)
>
> wives of Egyptian nationals holding proof of marriage. (except nationals of Syria, Iraq, Morocco and Qatar)

The same information appears in [Timatic](https://www.united.com/web/en-US/apps/vendors/default.aspx?i=timatic). You may have to bring this to the attention of the check-in clerk, but this is their official database.

[ADDED: Excerpt from Timatic link filled in for Egypt destination and Lebanon passport]

> Egypt - Destination Visa
>
> Visa required.
>
> The following are exempt from holding a visa:
>   Nationals of Lebanon with a normal passport and who are older than 50 years or younger than 16 years for a maximum stay of 3 months.
>
> Wives of Egyptian nationals.

Comment: Can you quote the relevant part of the Wikipedia article?  I don't see the words *wife, husband, spouse, family,* or *partner* anywhere on the page.  Also, I filled out the Timatic form you link to, indicating that the traveler is a resident of Egypt, and got "visa required" without any text mentioning marriage.  What text did you get, and how did you get it?

Comment: @phoog I filled in Timatic as Lebanese passport, Egypt destination, and left Residence blank. I would think _a fortiori_ holding an Egyptian residence permit would make the visa issue go away.

Comment: Purely out of interest, would it be necessary to prove that your husband was an Egyptian national if he wasn't accompanying you?

Comment: @DJClayworth wouldn't the Marriage certificate prove that?

Comment: I don't think marriage certificates show nationality of the parties.

Comment: California marriage licenses have birthplace, which can imply citizenship. So maybe Egyptian ones likewise. Another issue I thought of: is the license only in Arabic? I would think not, the OP must realize US officials are unlikely to read Arabic.